# Unhandled soft exception. java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo

Tags: java, android, react-native

My app was working fine on development mode.
And it used to work even in production mode a week ago.
But today when i built my app using `gradlew assembleRelease` and installed it on my android device, it gives me the error mentioned in title. Here is a log from `adb logcat`:

```
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:66)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.modules.deviceinfo.DeviceInfoModule.invalidate(DeviceInfoModule.java:114)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:110)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:108)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:359)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by NativeAnimatedModule
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:66)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule.invalidate(NativeAnimatedModule.java:897)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:110)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:108)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:359)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by FrescoModule
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:66)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.invalidate(FrescoModule.java:202)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:110)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:108)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:359)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
02-09 23:48:02.175 28030 28075 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
02-09 23:48:02.177 28030 28085 W unknown:ReactNative: Invoking JS callback after bridge has been destroyed.
02-09 23:48:02.177 28030 28084 W unknown:ReactNative: Invoking JS callback after bridge has been destroyed.
02-09 23:48:02.183 28030 28074 W unknown:ReactNative: Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed: RCTEventEmitter.receiveEvent([7,"topLayout",{"target":7,"layout":{"width":392.7272644042969,"y":0,"height":60,"x":0}}])
02-09 23:48:02.188 28030 28030 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative: Unable to handle Exception - catalystInstanceVariableExists: true - isCatalystInstanceAlive: true - hasExceptionHandler: true
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethodsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object reference
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.AnimationsManager.isLayoutAnimationEnabled(AnimationsManager.java:507)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReaLayoutAnimator.isLayoutAnimationEnabled(ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.java:191)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.manageChildren(ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.java:266)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$ManageChildrenOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:217)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:915)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1026)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$2.runGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:984)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run(GuardedRunnable.java:31)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
02-09 23:48:02.192 28030 28030 E unknown:ReactNative:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28086 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.wallet, PID: 28030
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethodsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object reference
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.handleException(ReactContext.java:425)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext$ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handleException(ReactContext.java:432)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run(GuardedRunnable.java:33)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.NativeMethodsHolder.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object reference
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.AnimationsManager.isLayoutAnimationEnabled(AnimationsManager.java:507)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReaLayoutAnimator.isLayoutAnimationEnabled(ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.java:191)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.manageChildren(ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.java:266)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$ManageChildrenOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:217)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:915)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1026)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$2.runGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:984)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run(GuardedRunnable.java:31)
02-09 23:48:02.193 28030 28030 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 7 more
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wallet",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.5",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.1.12",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.2.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "d3-shape": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-freeze": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.23",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "reselect": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**Note:**
The only new thing that i added recently was `react-native-firebase` package and FCM related packages. But i don't see any traces of them in the log from `logcat`

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve or find out any more information about this issue?  We too are seeing it and not sure what is happening/causing it.

Comment: I get those warnings right after I did something that caused an "Exception in native call
                                                                                                  kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property someVar has not been initialized". (supposed to crash in Native Android but didn't in React Native for me)

Comment: Got the same issue - RN 0.71, hermes enabled, using react-native-firebase packages as well - any idea?